# How to fetch a Firestore.instance.collection() that is a Future<String>?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm trying to fetch some data from my Firebase using Firestore.instance.collection(currentUser), but the currentUser is a Future.How can I accomplish this?

I have the following

```
class FoodCart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodCartState createState() => _FoodCartState();
}

class _FoodCartState extends State<FoodCart> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String currentUser;
    firebaseHelper().getCurrentUser().then((result){
      currentUser = result;
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("FoodCart"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(//recover data from firebase and shows in the listview
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(currentUser).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
            default:
              return new ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return foodCard(document['name'],document['description']);
                }).toList(),
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my firebaseHelper() i have:

```
...
    Future<String> getCurrentUser() async{
      FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      if(user != null){//if exists a current user, then
        return user.uid;
      }else{
        return null;
      }
    }
...
```

But in the **stream: Firestore.instance.collection(currentUser).snapshots()**,
the currentUser is always returning null, because currentUser = result is attributed inside the Future function (then).In other words, I need to use the result of a Future function inside a field that needs a String function.How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is re-render the view, this is done using the function `setState ({});`

```
class FoodCart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodCartState createState() => _FoodCartState();
}

class _FoodCartState extends State<FoodCart> {
// global variable
String currentUser;

// -------------- create this method to get the current user
 Future<Null> _getCurrentUser() async {
    var result = await firebaseHelper().getCurrentUser();

//we notified that there was a change and that the UI should be rendered
    setState(() {
      currentUser = result;
    });
  }
 // Add this method
  Widget buildBody() {
    if (this.currentUser == null) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(//recover data from firebase and shows in the listview
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(currentUser).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
            default:
              return new ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return foodCard(document['name'],document['description']);
                }).toList(),
              );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

// ------------ add this method
@override
  void initState() {
    this._getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("FoodCart"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      body: this.buildBody(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes you've proposed.In the app, it is working. But the strange fact is that the console.run is showing: The following assertion was thrown building FoodCart(dirty, state: _FoodCartState#14387):
I/flutter ( 5703): 'file:///C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/lib/src/firestore.dart':
I/flutter ( 5703): Failed assertion: line 68 pos 12: 'path != null': is not true.In other words, putting a print(currentUser); immediately after the Widget build(BuildContext context), I get sometimes the current user and sometimes null.

Comment: I understand, what I think happens is that if you put a breakpoint on the line `return Scaffold (` I guess you enter twice? right?

Comment: remember to vote for the answer that helps others to trust the response information

Answer (score 0):

Call something like

```
firebaseHelper().getCurrentUser().then((result){
  setState(() {
    currentUser = result;
  })
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do what you've said, but without success.The currentUser continues returning null...